# Dynamic Questionnaire in ASP.Net MVC, when httppost the model values are null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to develop some opinion poll type mvc application..so far i create my view model

```
public class SurveyCommonViewModel
{
    public List<SurveyQuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public class SurveyQuestionViewModel
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public String QuestionText{get;set;}
    public int QuestionResultId { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionOption
{
    public int QuestionOptionId { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
}
```

Now am confused how to design view? So that on next, prev question click I get updated models with fetched question and available options. As far I develop but I got model properties null view model on httppost.

My Controller Like :

```
public ActionResult Poll()
{
    SurveyCommonViewModel retVal = GetMockDataForSurvey();
    return View(retVal);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Poll(SurveyCommonViewModel scm)
{
    return View(scm);
}

 private SurveyCommonViewModel GetMockDataForSurvey()
    {
     SurveyCommonViewModel retVal = new SurveyCommonViewModel();
    retVal.Options = new List<QuestionOption>();
        retVal.Options.Add(new QuestionOption()
        {
            FriendlyName = "A",
            QuestionOptionId = 500
        });

        retVal.Options.Add(new QuestionOption()
        {
            FriendlyName = "B",
            QuestionOptionId = 501
        });
        retVal.Options.Add(new QuestionOption()
        {
            FriendlyName = "C",
            QuestionOptionId = 502
        });

       List<SurveyQuestionViewModel> questions = new List<SurveyQuestionViewModel>()
        {
            new SurveyQuestionViewModel()
            {
                QuestionId = 1,
                QuestionText = "Question 1 ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionViewModel()
            {
                QuestionId = 2,
                QuestionText = "Question 2 ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionViewModel()
            {
                QuestionId = 3,
                QuestionText = "Question 3 ?"
            },
            new SurveyQuestionViewModel()
            {
                QuestionId = 4,
                QuestionText = "Question 4 ?"
            }
      };
     retVal.Questions = questions;
    return retVal;
    }
```

my razor view is like :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
<label id="lblQuestion">@Model.Questions.Where(m => m.QuestionId== 1).FirstOrDefault().QuestionText.ToString()</label>
     @foreach (var option in Model.Options)
        {

                @Html.RadioButton("answer", @option.FriendlyName) @option.FriendlyName
  }
 <input type="submit" name="Next" value="Next"/>
  }
```

I want all these 4 questions one by one basis...on next button click I want to store this selected option to my view model...and display next question to end user..lastly on 4th question save button is there for updates view models.. I hope you understand what I actually want..... I am not clear about how can I create my razor view....that Is what actually want to be help it out by guys like you...please give me some ideas how can I create or design my razor view....mine view model is finalized...but razor view I cant be able to design...I am beginner to MVC Framework

How does this work?

Comment: Your creating `name` attributes which have no relationship at all to you model (`SurveyCommonViewModel` does not contain a property named `group-poll`!). And you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. Nothing in your code makes much sense - you use `@Model.CurrentQuestion.QuestionText.ToString` but the model does not even contain a property named `CurrentQuestion` so you have not even shown the correct models

Comment: Hii @Stephen Good Morning .... i edited my question ...now see that and help me out of this ...Thanks ☺

Comment: Now your creating radio buttons for an property named `answer` which also does not exist in your model. And you models really make no sense anyway. Surely each Question needs a collection of possible Answers relating to that question. And why are you passing a collection of Questions to the view when you appear to be creating a form based on only one question?